# Send account details to user email from django admin

Tags: django, email

I am trying to send an email to a user after the user account is created by the admin.

accounts/admin.py

```
class ProfileInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Profile
    can_delete = False
    verbose_name_plural = 'Profile'
    fk_name = 'user'

class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    inlines = (ProfileInline, )
    list_select_related = ( 'profile', )
    list_display = ('email', 'username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'is_staff')

    fieldsets = (
        ('Personal information', {'fields': ('first_name', 'last_name', 'username', 'email', 'password')}),
        ('Permissions', {'fields': ('is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser', 'groups', 'user_permissions')}),
        ('Important dates', {'fields': ('last_login', 'date_joined')}),
    )

    add_fieldsets = (
        ('None', {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2')}
        ),
    )

    def get_inline_instances(self, request, obj=None):
        if not obj:
            return list()
        return super(CustomUserAdmin, self).get_inline_instances(request, obj)

    def get_ordering(self, request):
        return ['-date_joined']

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        super(CustomUserAdmin, self).save_model(request, obj, form, change)
        obj.user = request.user
        obj.profile.email_confirmed = True
        obj.profile.save()
        print(obj)
        if not change:
            current_site = get_current_site(request)
            subject = 'Your Account Login Details'
            message = render_to_string('accounts/email/account_detail_email.html', {
                'user': obj.user,
                'domain': current_site.domain,
            })
            obj.user.email_user(subject, message)
```

Email header

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Subject: Your Account Login Details
From: ****@gmail.com
To: admin@admin.com
Date: Wed, 23 Aug 2017 11:21:41 -0000
Message-ID: <20170823112141.16912.15261@DESKTOP-BRG5003>
```

The email should go to user email not to the admin and from email should be the admin email.

when I print obj it shows the username of the user created.

Any help or suggestion is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It needs to be

```
obj.email_user(subject, message)
```

not

```
obj.user.email_user(subject, message)
```

If there is any other better way then please suggest :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Django custom admin action: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/actions/

Your admin class may look like this:

```
def send_account_details(modeladmin, request, queryset):
    # Your email sending code here.
    # The queryset contains selected users
    ...


class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    ...
    actions = [send_account_details]
```

Comment: Thanks for giving me another brilliant idea. It's not required to have a `admin action` at this moment but can use in future if needed.